# How to calculate "Sn = 1*1+2*2+3*3+...+n*n " (N>=1)

Tags: math, series

How to calculate this series `Sn=1*1+2*2+3*3+...+n*n where (n>1)`.
Please give me hint

Comment: You'd better to post it at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: First: you need parenthesis just like you do in math if you want to be sure to get the expected result! And, you'd be pleased to know, math is not English based, it's the "universal language".

Comment: Point your browser at: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+i%3D1..infinity+i%5E2#

Answer (score 6):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)

```
S = n * (n + 1) * (2*n + 1) / 6
```

It is easy to prove this using [induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Answer (score 6):

From [this page](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm), the following formula can be used

[image: Formula]

Please post **math** questions on http://math.stackexchange.com. SO is for programming-related questions.

Comment: ... then don't answer it, simply vote to close and move on? Just sayin

Comment: I did vote to close! It was his first question, so I answered :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering it.  Better to do that than to make a useless comment.